# Using Latitude and Longitude values in esy-osm-pbf to get amenities list at a given radius in Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I have a dataset that had latitude and longitude of some elements. I am trying to pull information regarding all the amenities around a particular latitude longitude. I have used overpass query and I am able to fetch the amenities. But, I want to use the OSM.pbf file downloaded directly in the python query. I was able to pull all amenities at a particular latitude longitude value using the following query

```
import esy.osm.pbf
osm = esy.osm.pbf.File('california-latest.osm.pbf')
amenities = [entry for entry in osm if entry.tags.get('amenity')]
```

After this I was able to pass lonlat value and get the amenities. Is there anyway I can pass the radius and longitude and latitude values in the code to get the required information

Code using overpass query. I want to replicate the following using the above method

```
import overpy
amenities = [] 
for latitude,longitude in zip(Dataset_Sample.Latitude, Dataset_Sample.Longitude):
    overpass_query = """[out:json][timeout:25]; node["amenity"](around:1000.0,"""+ str(latitude) + "," +str(longitude)+"); out;"
    response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query})
    response_json = response.json()
    amenities.append([element['tags']['amenity'] for element in response_json['elements']])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first element unfolds the structure of the object (`esy.osm.pbf.file.Node`):

```
amenities[0]
```

When you look closer, you see the `tags` itself is a `dict` inside the `Node` object:

```
type(amenities[0].tags)    # := dict
```

And so is the `longlat` too! (`tuple` inside `Node`):

```
type(amenities[0].longlat) # := tuple
```

So let's say you are looking for the "exact" coordinations `(long, lat)`, you just have to run the following piece of code:

```
for entry in osm :
   if entry.loglat == (long, lat)
       target = entry
       break
```

And you have the `Node` you are looking for in `target`. I guess you get the idea and know how to look for similar coordinations (using regex etc.)